# How do I switch Github Push/Pull from user/pass to SSH in VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh

I got an email from Github saying that they are deprecating user/pass authentication for git operations next summer. user/pass was what was using inside VSCode to push/pull.

I set up my SSH and added it to my github account. And I can connect from the command line properly:

```
sean@sean-ThinkPad-T480:~/.ssh$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi seanrasmussen! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

However, when I push/pull with VSCode's GUI, I think it is still using the old way. Not SSH. How do I force SSH instead in the VSCode GUI?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to change the URL to an SSH URL instead, like so: `git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git`.  How you do that in VS Code, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with VS Code. The URL of the remote repository is stored in your local repository.

1. Open a command-line/shell and cd to your code.
2. Then, check the current remote URL:

   `git remote -v`

   The result looks probably similar to this:

```
> origin  https://github.com/YOUR_GIHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/YOUR_GIHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME.git (push)
```

3. Change the URL to ssh:

   `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:YOUR_GIHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME.git`
4. (optionally) Check the remote URL again (it should now return the new URL):

   `git remote -v`

Now git will fetch/pull from/push to this new URL. This includes any git integrations into editors, IDEs, or git GUI clients.

Comment: I think it would be great for github to include this in the email they send out user/pass will be deprecated.

Comment: The part of this that has to do with VSCode, for me at least, is that I'm getting an error because VSCode doesn't seem to know about the running ssh-agent, have the environment variables set, and when it runs the git commands, it doesn't have any of what git needs in its environment to succeed.

Solutions are to run the `eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add ~/ssh/keyfile` and then launch `vscode` from that shell.

Is there a better way?